# multiple line graph in a single chart using google chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

tyring to ploat a comparison of two versions(aganist memory usage) in a single graph using google chart. 
In the graph i want to compares previous version 3.20.62 and latest version  3.21.50 performance aganist memory usage .X axis represnts corresponding
version build's uptime(3.21.50 starts at 1.24.22 AM and again restarts at 1.24.42 AM with a poling interval of 20 sec. Same in the case of 3.20.62).

No matter when the build starts. My intention is to show the memory usage of two versions at different restarts(like version starts at 1:24:22 then restarts at 1:24:42 and so and so..) 
intervals).In this graph it's difficult to
compare the memory usage of version 3.20.62 with 3.21.50 .because second line for version 3.20.62 starts at 14th pos in x axis.I have to start line for 3.20.62 from the 1st
position of Xaxis..so that i can compare the memory usage very easily...there is no importance of when the version build starts..

For example in the second restart of v.3.21.50 its memory usage is 970 and v.3.20.62 is 911 MB. i want to combine these lines as well .How can i do this?
I do not know how to implement this?Any idea?

code

```
function drawChart() {
        // Create our data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();           
        data.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});

        data.addRows([["1:24:22", 969]]);


        // Set additional chart options
        var myOptions = Object.assign({}, commonOptions);
        myOptions.pointSize = 3;           


        var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data1.addColumn('string', 'Tick');


        data1.addRows([["2:20:04", 911]]);


        var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data, data1, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
        chart.draw(joinedData, myOptions);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might get a better comparative view:

http://jsfiddle.net/XF7JE/491/

```js
var commonOptions = {
    titlePosition: "none",
    height: 350,
    width: 1024,
    pointShape: "circle",
    crosshair: {
      trigger: "both",
      color: "#A9A9A9"
    },

    chartArea: {
      top: 25,
      left: 70,
      width: "80%",
    },

    backgroundColor: {
      strokeWidth: 3,
      fill: "#F9F9F9"
    },
    legend: {
      position: "right"
    },
    hAxis: {
      slantedText: true,
      slantedTextAngle: 90,
    },
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true
    },
    vAxis: {
      gridlines: {
        count: -1,
        color: "#000000"
      },
      minorGridlines: {
        count: 1
      }
    }
  },
  releases = [{
    vs: '3.21.50',
    data: [
      ["1:24:22", 969, "Uptime: 1:24:22<br/>Memory Used: 969 MB"],
      ["1:24:42", 970, "Uptime: 1:24:42<br/>Memory Used: 970 MB"],
      ["1:25:03", 972, "Uptime: 1:25:03<br/>Memory Used: 972 MB"],
      ["1:25:23", 973, "Uptime: 1:25:23<br/>Memory Used: 973 MB"],
      ["1:25:43", 974, "Uptime: 1:25:43<br/>Memory Used: 974 MB"],
      ["1:26:03", 975, "Uptime: 1:26:03<br/>Memory Used: 975 MB"],
      ["1:26:23", 978, "Uptime: 1:26:23<br/>Memory Used: 978 MB"],
      ["1:26:43", 399, "Uptime: 1:26:43<br/>Memory Used: 399 MB"],
      ["1:27:03", 906, "Uptime: 1:27:03<br/>Memory Used: 906 MB"],
      ["1:27:23", 1231, "Uptime: 1:27:23<br/>Memory Used: 1231 MB"],
      ["1:27:43", 483, "Uptime: 1:27:43<br/>Memory Used: 483 MB"],
      ["1:28:03", 800, "Uptime: 1:28:03<br/>Memory Used: 800 MB"],
      ["1:28:23", 1079, "Uptime: 1:28:23<br/>Memory Used: 1079 MB"]
    ]
  }, {
    vs: '3.20.62',
    data: [
      ["2:20:04", 911, "Uptime: 2:20:04<br/>Memory Used: 911 MB"],
      ["2:20:24", 914, "Uptime: 2:20:24<br/>Memory Used: 914 MB"],
      ["2:20:44", 916, "Uptime: 2:20:44<br/>Memory Used: 916 MB"],
      ["2:21:04", 920, "Uptime: 2:21:04<br/>Memory Used: 920 MB"],
      ["2:21:24", 921, "Uptime: 2:21:24<br/>Memory Used: 921 MB"],
      ["2:21:44", 924, "Uptime: 2:21:44<br/>Memory Used: 924 MB"],
      ["2:22:04", 927, "Uptime: 2:22:04<br/>Memory Used: 927 MB"],
      ["2:22:24", 639, "Uptime: 2:22:24<br/>Memory Used: 639 MB"],
      ["2:22:44", 685, "Uptime: 2:22:44<br/>Memory Used: 685 MB"],
      ["2:23:04", 803, "Uptime: 2:23:04<br/>Memory Used: 803 MB"],
      ["2:23:24", 827, "Uptime: 2:23:24<br/>Memory Used: 827 MB"],
      ["2:23:44", 853, "Uptime: 2:23:44<br/>Memory Used: 853 MB"],
      ["2:24:04", 941, "Uptime: 2:24:04<br/>Memory Used: 941 MB"]
    ]
  }];

releases.forEach(function(r){
  k = 0;
  r.data.forEach(function(d){ 
    d[0] = ++k;
  });
});

function drawChart() {
  // Create our data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Tick');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Release Version:  3.21.50');
  data.addColumn({
    'type': 'string',
    'role': 'tooltip',
    'p': {
      'html': true
    }
  });

  data.addRows(releases[0].data);


  // Set additional chart options
  var myOptions = Object.assign({}, commonOptions);
  myOptions.pointSize = 3;
  myOptions.hAxis['showTextEvery'] = 1;
  myOptions.vAxis['viewWindow'] = {};
  myOptions.vAxis['format'] = "##### MB";
  myOptions.interpolateNulls = true;
  // myOptions.seriesType= 'bars';


  var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data1.addColumn('number', 'Tick');
  data1.addColumn('number', 'Previous Version:  3.20.62');
  data1.addColumn({
    'type': 'string',
    'role': 'tooltip',
    'p': {
      'html': true
    }
  });


  data1.addRows(releases[1].data);


  var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data, data1, 'full', [
    [0, 0]
  ], [1], [1]);
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
  chart.draw(joinedData, myOptions);
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  packages: ['corechart'],
  callback: drawChart
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?fake=.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?fake=.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: great..if you dont minf could you please explain what is doing in the releases variable....

Comment: It's changing the tick value from the actual time to a number. Since you are not interested in that time but rather in the order (first, second, third, etc) of restarts so you can compare first restart of one version against the other, it just aligns that.

Comment: Basically you have to force your series to have same X value so you can see them one over the other :)

Comment: No. I just added `vs` in there so you know what data is listed below.

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck with it!

Comment: this code snippet{code}releases.forEach((r) => {{code}  returns the Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154331/discussion-between-bluehipy-and-psl).

Comment: Hello instead of number values in x axis Let’s treat the axis as proper time and label with HH:MM:SS format .So first tick would be 00:01:00 instead of 1.0

How can i change my google API code accordingly? Please reply

Comment: @Psl Check the updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/XF7JE/509/ Data is aligned to first set of time ticks.

Comment: I tried out this way....but the final graph returned to initial stage :-(   http://jsfiddle.net/XF7JE/514/...could you please check

Comment: yea that approach (scaling the x axis based on the current time) is not suitable in this case ..becasue the x axis represents the uptime of a build.that means the time in which build starts .so if we put current time in x axis not suitable in this case

Comment: There is an option on `hAxis` named `showTextEvery` for huge data , or for all data, you can decide to not show more than 10 ticks, for example:  `myOptions.hAxis['showTextEvery'] = Math.floor(releases[0].data.length/10);`    http://jsfiddle.net/XF7JE/523/

Comment: but it does not shows the last uptime data in x axis. x axis is limited to 2:0:20 but its last value is of data[0] is 6:55:25

Comment: if we are limited to 2.0.20 the chart representation of uptime values after 2.0.20 will be missed out.

Comment: No. The 6:.. in original is transformed to 2.0.... because of the normalisation we re doing whith that step of 0.0.20.

Comment: True but these are your inputs and graphic restrictions :)

Comment: yes :-) :-).but am not aware of how we can limit or normalize all these in google char api....i dont know i have to find a suitable solution for this .

Comment: Doesn't matter what you display for x as long as data is huge and you ave to choose to show only discrete values every dx intervals specified by `showTextEvery`

Comment: I just told you, When you specify `showTextEvery` you are choosing from how many to how many to display something. If x values are [1,2,3,4,5,6] and you specify a showTextEvery=2 the displayed values will be [2,4,6]

Comment: thank you Thank you once again for whole support and patience....Finally my problem is resolved....http://jsfiddle.net/XF7JE/531/

Comment: Thanks! I'm from Romania. I think  it is visible in my profile ;)

Comment: can you please help me to resolve this js error .am facing some js erros's when ever the google chart data varies.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47149676/google-chartfix-the-uncaught-in-promise-error